# how to change the default user after import old wsl tar package?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use `--import` to setup the the wsl with my old wsl tar package, the following is the command:
`wsl --import ubuntu1804 c:\WSL c:\temp\ubuntu1804.tar`

It works fine except that the default user of wsl is root.
I got the help message from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about 
the suggestion is use the command like `ubuntu config` or `ubuntu18.04 config` ...
but since I setup wsl with 'import' mode, there isn't ubuntu* binary in my system

Do you know how to change the default user of wsl?

Comment: Recommend checking out [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1566022/1210833) for more updated (and on-topic) answers.

Answer (score 8):

Go to RegEdit.exe and look for your imported distribution:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ **guid** \DefaultUid and change its value by (usually) 1000.

Also with more recent Windows versions 2004 or (1903 and 1909 with the latest updates) you can edit the file /etc/wsl.conf (you can create it) and add:

```
[user]
default=yourusername
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Ubuntu 18.04**, the command to change default user is

```
ubuntu1804 config --default-user <username>
```

I found it thanks to this [post](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/128152-set-default-user-windows-subsystem-linux-distro-windows-10-a.html#option2).

Comment: This actually worked for me and the upvoted accepted answer did not. That said I used ubuntu2204 config --default-user <my-username>